# Ruby on Rails test fixture given id of 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, fixtures

I have a `User` model and a `UsageRecord` model that has a foreign key of a `user_id`. My YAML fixtures are like this:

`test/fixtures/users.yml`

```
user_one:
  email: email@address.com
```

`test/fixtures/usage_records.yml`

```
one:
  user_id: user_one
```

If I run `rake test` a test fails because the `user_id` on a `UsageRecord` is not valid. If I run `RAILS_ENV=test rails c` and examine the database, sure enough the `user_id` of the only `UsageRecord` has an ID of 0 (which doesn't match the user ID in the `Users` table).

What am I doing wrong here? I want it to have the user ID of 293267324 which matches the generated `User` model.

**UPDATE** I found the problem. Instead of specifying `user_id`, I had to use the association name instead. Switching the `UsageRecord` YAML to `user: one` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use the *association name* not the *column name* that will end up having the value. For instance, instead of setting `user_id` for the `UsageRecord`, set the `user`. This will perform the linking properly.